# Spring reactor executing consumers asynchronously

Tags: spring, asynchronous, reactor

Hi I am trying out Spring reactor so far everything works but my consumers are invoked one after the other ..synchronously

My use case :

The events are published from a restful controller and two simple consumer which prints to console are invoked (In reality one consumer writes to DB and the other publishes the data to a web socket)

I am using spring boot 1.2.7

This is my controller

```
    @Controller
    public class MessageController {    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myreactor")
    private Reactor r;  
    @RequestMapping("/hello/{username}")
    public  @ResponseBody String  welcome(@PathVariable String username) {      
        r.notify("MessageCreated", Event.wrap(username));
        return username;        
    }
}
```

My event handlers

Handler 1

```
 @Consumer
  public class MessageConsumer {    
      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("myreactor")
      private Reactor reactor;

      @Selector("MessageCreated")    
      public void handleRequest(Event<String> evt) {
          System.out.println("Called Handler 1 " +evt.getData());
      }
}
```

Handler 2

```
    @Consumer
     public class MessageConsumer2 {    
      @Autowired
      @Qualifier("myreactor")
      private Reactor reactor;

       @Selector("MessageCreated")   
      public void handleRequest(Event<String> evt) {        
          System.out.println("Called Handler 2 "+ evt.getData());             
      }
}
```

My reactor configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactor
public class ReactorConfiguration {

        @Bean
        Environment env() {
            return new Environment();
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("myreactor")
        Reactor myreactor(Environment env) {            
            return Reactors.reactor()
                    .env(env)
                    .dispatcher(Environment.THREAD_POOL)
                    .get();                  
        }
}
```

Whatever I do the result is always

```
Called Handler 1 Hello
Called Handler 2 Hello
```

Consumer are invoked in the same order
...please do let m know where did I mess up..The above is a mock implementation as I cant paste the original code here.